# Run Ethereum node with custom requirements

Tags: nodes, full-node, disk-space

I want to run my own Ethereum Mainnet node. I need it for an analytics system that will need to query blocks that are at most 24 hours old. I don't care if the node syncs regularly during the day - I only need it for creating a fork using ganache-cli and to query smart contract information (token names, total supply, token symbol).

Is a full node usable for fetching 24h old data? An archive node would probably be best, but this is way too expensive with the amount of disk space required. I would even prefer to reduce the required disk space from the full node somehow. I can buy another 1TB SSD for this purpose, but it will be a problem when the blockchain gets bigger in the future.

A light node would be no option for my application, as it will send tons of requests to the node.